# React + Formik + Firebase/Firestore Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:, [FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.]

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, formik

Making an instagram clone and it won't let me post a picture. I keep getting this error 'Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:, [FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.]' whenever I enter the page to upload a picture. My guess is that it's coming from the onSnapshot function. I also get the 'Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm(), [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'currentLoggedInUser.username')]' when I press the share button. Nothing happens beyond that point. Its supposed to take me back to the homescreen afterwards:

```
import { View, Text, Image, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import { Formik } from 'formik'
import { Divider } from 'react-native-elements'
import validUrl from 'valid-url'
import {db, firebase} from '../../firebase'

const PLACEHOLDER_IMG = 'https://pacificpatiostructures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/import_placeholder.png'

const uploadPostSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    imageUrl: Yup.string().url().required('A URL is required'),
    caption: Yup.string().max(2200, 'Caption has reached the character limit.')
})

const FormikPostUploader = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [thumbnailUrl, setThumbnailUrl] = useState(PLACEHOLDER_IMG)
    const [currentLoggedInUser, setCurrentLoggedInUser] = useState(null)
    
    const getUsername = () => {
        const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
        const unsubscribe = db
        .collection('user')
        .where('owner_uid', '==', 'user.uid').limit(1).onSnapshot(
            snapshot => snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                setCurrentLoggedInUser({
                    username: doc.data().username,
                    profilePicture: doc.data().profile_picture,
                })
            }) 
        )
        return unsubscribe
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getUsername()
    }, [])

    const uploadPostToFirebase = (imageUrl, caption) => {
        const unsubscribe = db
            .collection('users')
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email).collection('posts')
            .add({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                user: currentLoggedInUser.username,
                profile_picture: currentLoggedInUser.profilePicture,
                owner_uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
                caption: caption,
                createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                likes: 0,
                likes_by_users: [],
                comments: [],
            })
            .then(() => navigation.goBack())
        return unsubscribe
    }



  return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{caption: '', imageUrl: ''}}
        onSubmit={values => {
            uploadPostToFirebase(values.imageUrl, values.caption)
        }}
        validationSchema={uploadPostSchema}
        validateOnMount={true}
        >

            {({ 
                handleBlur, 
                handleChange, 
                handleSubmit, 
                values, 
                errors, 
                isValid 
            }) => (
                <>
                <View 
                    style={{ 
                        margin: 20, 
                        justifyContent: 'space-between', 
                        flexDirection: 'row', 
                    }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: validUrl.isUri(thumbnailUrl) ? thumbnailUrl : PLACEHOLDER_IMG}} 
                            style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}/>

                    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 12 }}>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20 }}
                            placeholder='Write a caption...' 
                            placeholderTextColor='gray'
                            multiline={true}
                            onChangeText={handleChange('caption')}
                            onBlur={handleBlur('caption')}
                            value={values.caption}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <Divider width = {0.2} orientation='vertical' />
                <TextInput 
                    onChange={(e) => setThumbnailUrl(e.nativeEvent.text)}
                    style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 18 }}
                    placeholder='Enter Image Url' 
                    placeholderTextColor='gray'
                    onChangeText={handleChange('imageUrl')}
                    onBlur={handleBlur('imageUrl')}
                    value={values.imageUrl}
                />
                {errors.imageUrl &&(
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>
                        {errors.imageUrl}
                    </Text>
                )}

                <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title='Share' disabled={!isValid}/>
                </>
            )}
          
      </Formik>
  )
}

export default FormikPostUploader
```

Here are my security rules that I used in Cloud Firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
  function userIsAuthenticated() {
        return request.auth != null;
    }
  // security rule for group collection ('post')
    match /{path=**}/posts/{postId} {
        allow read, write: if userIsAuthenticated();
    }
    
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read, write: if userIsAuthenticated();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alan Perez , have you checked my posted answer? Let me know if you have questions or clarifications about it. Also, See: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getUsername()` function queries `user` collection which is not included in your Firestore Rules which returns `Missing or insufficient permissions.`

As per this [**documentation**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions):

> Cloud Firestore security rules evaluate each query against its potential result and fails the request if it could return a document that the client does not have permission to read. Queries must follow the constraints set by your security rules.

You should also add necessary permissions to the `user` collection. See sample rule below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    function userIsAuthenticated() {
        return request.auth != null;
    }

    // security rule for group collection ('post')
    match /{path=**}/posts/{postId} {
        allow read, write: if userIsAuthenticated();
    }
    
    match /users/{usersId} {
        allow read, write: if userIsAuthenticated();
    }

    // Security Rule for `user` collection.
    match /user/{userId} {
        allow read, write: if userIsAuthenticated();
    }
  }
}
```